# How to find if an array of strings has a substring?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array of strings. I need to find if any of the strings has a particular substring

```
array = ["Number", "Subtotal(Kilobytes/sec)", "Total(Kilobytes/sec)", "Usage"]
```

For example, if I was looking for the substring "kilobytes' at 2nd & 3rd element in the array I used:

```
array[2].inlcude? "kilobytes"
array.include?("kilobytes")
```

which works in irb but on script run its throwing :

```
NoMethodError:
  undefined method `inlcude?' for "Total(Kilobytes/sec)":String
```

or

```
NoMethodError:
  undefined method `inlcude?' for #<Array:0x000000049bb780>
```

Why is it not working in the script or any other better way to find if a substring exists or not?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO!  In the future please use the "Tags" section to specify what language you are using rather than including it in the title.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a simple typo. Use `include?` instead of `inlcude?`

Answer (score 0):

```
array.any?{|s| s =~ "kilobytes"}
```